# How can I transfer data from Macbook to Ubuntu desktop using Crossover cable?

Tags: 16.04, ethernet, macbook

I have a crossover cable connected between my Macbook and Ubuntu 16.04 box, what do I need to do now to setup the transfer of data between them?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, not sure why you'd be using/needing a crossover cable (From here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2178081?start=0&tstart=0
"... for years the Mac's ethernet ports have had the ability to reverse the polarity of the signals if a crossover is needed, automatically. No need for special cables when hooking up to a Mac.")

To get you started, both PC's need to be on the same LAN so they can see each other. Setup a static IP address on each PC.
E.g:
Mac-192.168.1.1
Ubuntu-192.168.1.2
Netmask for both 255.255.255.0

Try to ping each PC: Mac to Ubuntu: ping 192.169.1.2

Helpful links:

[How to share files between Ubuntu and OSX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3815/how-to-share-files-between-ubuntu-and-osx)

https://superuser.com/questions/842924/directly-connect-macbook-to-linux-desktop-via-ethernet-for-fast-ssh

Answer (score 0):

You will ned, on both computers:

1. Identify the name of interface for crossover cable
2. Assign an ip-address to each interface, that doesn't interfere with already used addresses. If computers are called 192.168.0.x, you could use 10.0.1.x
3. Set up a route for the chosen ip-address / interface combination.