# Ubuntu 16.04 ~ new install, working but now no internet connection since local connection

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-software

I've setup a new box with Ubuntu 16.04, and everything was working fine but now I can't connect to the internet and gnome-software won't load either.  Apparently there may be a bug to do with gnome-software, but also since connecting my box with my macbook to exchange data locally this has happened.

ifconfig is displaying enp3s0, and I can't ping www.google.com.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this or what the issue is I would be most grateful.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you did, what suggestions have you followed here http://askubuntu.com/questions/875169/how-can-i-transfer-data-from-macbook-to-ubuntu-desktop-using-crossover-cable and what was the result.

Comment: PS - Don't you have a router?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just went to Network Connections and added a new ethernet connection, then deleted the connection that I was not able to access the internet with.  A bit hacky, but was a solution atleast.