# Trying to connect to MacBook: Password etc. doesn't work (Files -> Other Locations -> "MacBook Pro" under Networks.)

Tags: networking, mac

On [How to share files between Ubuntu and OSX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3815/how-to-share-files-between-ubuntu-and-osx) I found these apparently easy instructions on how to connect to my Mac from Ubuntu:

> In mac OS, go to **System preferences > sharing** and enable **Personal File Sharing**
>
> In Ubuntu open DashHome and open the **Files** folder. (or however you know how to get to the files folder.)
>
> In the sidebar, choose **Browse Network**
>
> As long as the two machines are on the same network, your mac should be in there as a directory that you can mount within Ubuntu.

On Ubuntu 20.04 I open **Files** (also called Nautilus) **> Other Locations*,I choose **MacBook Pro ...** under **Networks**. Then a window pops up asking for Username, Domain, Password. But no matter whether I use name and password for the Mac or Ubuntu it doesn't work. And what is "Domain"? I tried "Staff" (and "WORKGROUP"). Nothing works!

PS: The Mac is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running MacOS Catalina Ver. 10.15.7. It seems to be using SMB for networking.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to the MacBook from Ubuntu I had to use Terminal commands.

```
$ cd /mnt
/mnt$ sudo mkdir macbook
/mnt$ sudo  mount -v  -t  cifs  //macbook-pro-henrik.local/henrik  /mnt/macbook  -o  user="Henrik"
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.227,unc=\\macbook-pro-henrik.local\henrik,user=Henrik,pass=********
/mnt$
```

The functionality in Ubuntu Files is VERY primitive. I would call it a waste of time... It doesn't give any error messages. It doesn't even tell you that you need to install this:

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Comment: PS: This still really doesn't work. You only get read access to the MacBook... Even after a longer dialogue with 2 helpful people here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252656492?page=2